# R plotly scatter3d: How to make nearest marker appear the biggest?

Tags: r, plot, plotly, bioinformatics, scatter3d

Currently my code looks like this:

```
library(plotly)

count = data.frame(
    row.names = c("Cell1", "Cell2", "Cell3", "Cell4", "Cell5", "Cell6"),
    Gene1 = c(10, 11, 8, 3, 2, 1),
    Gene2 = c(6, 4, 5, 3, 2.8, 1),
    Gene3 = c(12, 9, 10, 2.5, 1.3, 2),
    Gene4 = c(5, 7, 6, 2, 4, 7),
    
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

threeD = plotly::plot_ly(
    data = count,
    x = ~Gene1,
    y = ~Gene2,
    z = ~Gene3,
    type = "scatter3d",
    mode = "markers",
    marker = list(size = 20),
    color = row.names(count)
)
threeD
```

This code generates following output:
[image: Plotly scatter3d plot]

I would like to make the marker scale with the distance. So the markers nearest to "me" is bigger (Cell1 & Cell 2) and the markers far away appear smaller (Cell5 & Cell6). This would achieve a more realistic 3D feeling.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to make a kind of "bubble" plot by assigning a list of size to the markers so that they grow according to their respective value along the z-axis. The simplest way is to reuse the same data and apply some scaling function (product, log, etc.) as needed for example :

```
marker = list(size = c(12, 9, 10, 2.5, 1.3, 2)*5)
```

The problem is that if you change your point of view, the markers won't update magically for the intended 3D feeling.

You can also use color scaling by adding the `colorscale` property to the marker object, for example :

```
colorscale = c('#FFE1A1', '#683531')
```

Comment: Than you! Going to try this! :)